# Do most Hotels book an extra person fee?

Tags: hotels

I booked a hotel for 4 person with a double bed. should I expect a surprise surcharge for this booking. I booked on Hotels.com. and am worried about getting the surcharge but cant find any info about it. The main question is is if they charge extra normally.

I have already booked a hotel http://www.marriott.com/hotels/travel/atlaa-fairfield-inn-and-suites-atlanta-airport-south-sullivan-road/

Comment: If you vote to close question add a reason why please. And I will edit the question to be more suitable

Comment: This is opinion based. Who can give you any accurate data on most hotels? There are thousands of hotels in the world and even in the USA.

Comment: You are right. Would a better question be does Hotels.com catch all of the hidden fees? or is that still opinion based?

Comment: You can always call or email the hotel to check. You will get the answer for this particular hotel instead of a general answer which may not apply.

Answer (score 3):

*Most* hotels charge different rates for the same room depending on how many gusts will be using it.

But this should not be a *surprise*. If you book the room through somewhere like hotels.com and enter "1 room, 4 occupants", it ought to show you the hotel's rates for that occupancy, not something else that a surcharge will later be added to.

If you have *already* booked a room, but made the booking for fewer people than you will actually be, you should contact the hotel **now** and ask about  changing your booking to be for more occupants. This may involve an increase in rates, of course.

Comment: With all due respect, I'm not entirely sure about this. My experience outside Italy in the past has always been that you book the room, and you pay the room price, and the official prices signs you find inside hotels are usually listing just the room price, nowhere I saw a booking for person. Was the case you are saying, one could just rent a 6 bed room for himself paying the cost for only one person, which quite a bit unrealistic and illogical

Comment: @motoDrizzt: Nothing obliges the hotel to have a single-occupancy rate for a 6-bed room -- or if they do, nothing obliges them to have _the same_ single occupancy rate for that room that they have for their 1-bed rooms. It is certainly common in my experience to have lower rates for "2 beds, 1 person", than for "2 beds, 2 persons". But it is of course possible that my experience is atypical.

Answer (score 2):

Some hotels do, some don't. I dont think anyone has statistics on if this is *most* or not. Hotels charge per room, per guest or a base rate for *n*-guests plus fee for additional guests. All these are common options and, depending where you travel, you might see more of one type or other. There are also a number of other rules such as children under *Y* age stay free with paying parents.

While this makes a lot of options, once booked for the correct number of guests, this should not be a surprise. The booking should have the full price, sometimes excluding local taxes and tourism fees, for the room given the number of people requested. Many online booking sites also specify which fees are excluded below the price on the booking confirmation.